# Is pickpocketing large amounts of gold in Skyrim bugged?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been experimenting a fair bit with... let's call it, "reducing the chance of future spinal issues due to excess load" of various townsfolk. While engaging in this public-health improvement activity, I've noticed that while my pickpocket chances for most items are perfectly stable, anytime an NPC is carrying large amount of gold (over 1000), the rules for relieving them of their gold stash seem to become truly bizarre and unstable.

Example:

> Target: Giraud Gemane, Solitude Bardic College
> Gold: 1610
>
> My stats:
> Pickpocket: 100
> Light Fingers: rank 2 (+40% bonus)
> Cutpurse: Yes (+50% bonus)
>
> Attempt 1: No gear
> Displayed success chance: 15%
>
> Attempt 2: Closed pickpocket window, reopened without changing anything or either character moving.
> Displayed success chance: 65%
>
> Attempt 3: Closed window, equipped Fine Boots enchanted with +40% pickpocket
> Displayed success chance: 55%
>
> Attempt 4: Closed window, reopened; still have boots equipped.
> Displayed success chance: 5%
>
> Attempt 5: Closed window, equipped Gloves enchanted with +40% pickpocket bonus.
> Displayed success chance: 0%

From tinkering around a lot with different NPCs and gold amounts it feels like every time I open the pickpocket window, I will either get a "good" base pickpocket chance of 65% or a "bad" base pickpocket chance of 15%. From there, every pickpocket bonus item I equip actually *reduces* my chance of success by about 10%.

Again, this only appears to kick in for NPCs with over 1000-ish gold. Under that amount, I have a 90% success chance every single time regardless of equipment.

Can anyone offer an explanation for this behavior, or is this a bizarre bug of some kind?

Comment: You know how much weights 1000 septims?

Comment: The good vs. bad chance is the difference between you attempting this while seen/unseen by your mark. You say neither of you is moving, but he's swiveling his head around I'm sure, and theres a pulse of some sort as well.

Comment: That strikes me as odd since I'm not "detected" (full closed-eye indicator for stealth) when trying this.

Comment: @M'vy — According to Skyrim, [nothing at all](http://cloud.steampowered.com/ugc/648745380530960858/56D0FCC82AA152803DC120621FD8FC280E93EC8A/)! :-)

Comment: i also have the problem people saying its the light or whatever havent done this, it seems like a screw up in the formula, because after 1000 or so gold it gets buggy and u have to open and close the pickpocketing window to get a non zero percent number aswell as pickpocketing enchants making u less likely to steal the gold

Comment: I agree it seems bugged to an indecipherable degree.. My pickpocketing is 85, and as a max enchanter I have a ring and necklace on each with +40% pickpocket success and the thieves guild boots adding another 15% on top of that.. and I still get 0% for no reason sometimes.. ok I thought, maybe he's just extremely perceptive (downs a pickpocketing potion for another 50% on top of that.. still getting 0%) it's actually happened with the "quest item" on the repeatable "fishing quest" several times as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to your stealth meter changing due to NPCs moving, or dynamics lights touching you or not.   The closer you are to being detected the less likely you are to succeed.

Comment: I took care to watch the light and shadow, and the direction the NPC was looking. I don't think that was it, unfortunately. And even if it was, it would not explain why putting on pickpocket bonus items consistently reduces the chance to succeed.

Comment: Well, as with many RPG's  there could be %chance of getting a good base roll.  There is a perk that allows you to steal gold easily.  If you get this perk and seem to get more stables results, then I would guess that 1000g is the limit for your thieving skill, where you get lower results more often than not regardless of equipment.  The only way to test this would be to try it a lot, record the results then compare.  I am currently beating the game.  When I am done I will do some testing.  When ModKit is realeased, we will probably get accurate formulas.

Answer (score -2):

This is a glitch and it's probably bugged. What you're wearing might do the opposite effect. Unequip the enchanted gear to see if the chances of taking gold are possible. If that doesn't work, place a paralyze potion or use Unrelenting Force on them, when theyare getting up, pickpocket them and you can take the gold even when it's a 0% chance.