# How can I pickpocket only some of the gold?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

There are some people in Skyrim running around with a lot of money, I'd like to relieve them of their burden. Unfortunatly, my pickpocketing skills are not up to it for larger sums of gold. I can steal smaller sums, but for very high amounts of gold I get a 0% chance of pickpocketing.

Is there any way to steal only part of the gold someone is carrying?

Comment: Probably not. Think of the mechanics of a cut purse.

Comment: Related: [Is pickpocketing large amounts of gold in Skyrim bugged?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/36264/1980)

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can! You just need to place Paralysis potions in their pockets. After they recover and try to get up quickly pickpocket the gold. It will still say 0% chance but they won't notice it gone and will remain neutral.

Answer (score 3):

You can't select just part of a stack of gold coins. This way, you could rob people of 2000g with just stealing 100 at a time. What I did was I used perks in the pickpocketing tree, potions of pickpocketing and various items. And that increased my chance of success quite a lot.

Also, I think it was a bug but whenever I would access somebody's 'pockets' and gold was the first item, the chance of success was 20%. If I rolled over a couple more items with my mouse and returned on the gold, I'd have 0% chance. So I ended up not using my mouse at all and pressing 'e' to access the character's pocket and 'e' again to loot the gold, at 20% chance.

Comment: Well, the whole point of stealing 100g at a time would be that there'd still be a high percentage that at least one time you'd be caught. If they had added the ability, it would have included a reduction in chance, possibly....

Answer (score 1):

Simple: you can't. All gold is considered "one item," just like in your own inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not able to steal small amounts, its either nothing or the whole lot. Some advice for you my friend

At a low pickpocketing level, you'll be really bad at stealing any of it;

First you'll need to get your level up higher, and then you will see the % of items going up, also, you will want to acquire some perks in the pickpocketing tree.

My advice is to keep track of those with big money in their inventory, and only take smaller items from them, like food, keys and other invaluable items, thus putting your level up some what, remember to go to the guardian stones and select the thief stone to help your pickpocketing level rise that 20% faster, if not done already

Maybe invest in some items that put your pickpocketing up some percentages, like gloves, ring, Armour etc.

Or if you don't want to wear it all the time, buy a house and put them into your chest for when you do wish to use them, for when your brave enough to try again.

Always save your game before you try it, because you never know when they will catch you, sometimes the first item, sometimes the 3rd or not at all.

So hope this helps, good luck and go forth and cause havoc

Thanks for reading

Rob

Answer (score 0):

There's a very simple way which always works, just like the paralysis. Use the ice form shout then as they just thaw make sure you are hidden and pick their pocket.